# ServerSide JavaScript File I/O

Tags: javascript, tomcat, file-io

I'm using ServerSide JavaScript as part of an Apache Tomcat solution. Does anyone know if there is any way to read/write file contents using JavaScript on the server side. Just to be clear, the JavaScript is running on the server, not in the browser.

Comment: Yes, definitely; from JavaScript you can get at any package/class in the Java SDK, including the `java.io` classes. (That is, if you're using Rhino, either directly or through the `ScriptEngine` stuff.)

Comment: Is there a tutorial or sample script somewhere that I can use as a reference/example?

Comment: Well it's pretty basic stuff; anything you're using should have basic docs for how to get to Java from JavaScript and to JavaScript from Java. [Here's one from the first Google result page](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) searching for "access Java from JavaScript ScriptEngine"

Comment: Thanks Pointy. Of course it's always basic when you know what to look for :) I'm new to Java, so a friendly point in the right direction is most welcome. Thanks again.

Comment: OK good - I didn't mean to say that it's super-simple, but that it's kind-of fundamental to the whole idea of using Java & JavaScript together, and thus that you should be able to find information pretty easily. Searching for anything involving Java and JavaScript does churn up a lot of noise, however.

Comment: Yes it does. Actually your hint about Rhino is just the bit of information I needed. I see that Rhino is installed on the server and I assume that is what is being used. Thanks again.